# create mysql view for many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql

MYSQL script to create a MYSQL view Table to show use id , email , and the assigned role/s name/s through many-to-many relationship

I wrote the script and joined tables to create the view table but it shows role name for the first record only the other users has null although they have roles!.

Tables

```
    users (id, email)
    roles (id, name)
    role_users (id, user_id, role_id)
```

My script

```
    DROP VIEW IF EXISTS users_view;
    CREATE VIEW users_view AS
       SELECT users.id AS user_id, users.email, roles_names.role_name 
         FROM users
    LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT role_users.user_id AS roles_user_id,
               role_users.role_id AS roles_role_id
          FROM role_users
    ) AS user_roles ON (roles_user_id = users.id)
    LEFT JOIN(
           SELECT roles.id AS roleid, roles.name AS role_name 
            FROM  roles
     ) AS roles_names ON (roleid = user_roles.roles_user_id)
```

view created success but it shows the role name for the first user only , other users has role_name  value of null although they have records at role_users table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    SELECT u.id AS user_id, u.email, IFNULL(u_roles.role_name,'') as role_name 
      FROM users u 
 LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT r.name SEPARATOR ',') as role_name, ur.user_id 
           FROM roles r INNER JOIN user_roles ur 
              ON r.id = ur.role_id 
       GROUP BY ur.user_id) u_roles 
              ON  u.id = u_roles.user_id
```

Since role users will be having all only roles from roles table, inner join on roles and user_roles will be fine. 
By this query all records which are having an entry in user_roles table will show role name and rest of the users will be having `null` as role name (adding `IFNULL` check to make null values an empty string)

Comment: Than you , but if user have more than one role it creates a new record for the same user with the same details but with different role name! how to keep only one record for each user and if user have more than one role, then it show as example "Admin, User"

Comment: Yes, you can use group_concat in for the same

Comment: Thank you but this shows all 3 role names at the first user although this use has only 2 roles not 3,  then all other users with role_name value of null ! 

maybe 
```
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT()
```

should be used at role_id from role_users (pivot table) not role_name from roles table ?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de00664/1/0 Please check this sqlfiddle, here the results are as expepcted

Comment: Yes all working great , what i was missing is Group By, thank you very much , this is a correct answer )

Comment: Very good example thank you very much.